# How to adjust sound of QWebView based Qt Application

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

I have created a Qt GUI application which has QWebView object to open a URL which has embedded flash content. My problem is that I would like to control the audio volume of my Qt Application(QWebView), but I am not able to find any way to do so.

However I came across classes from the Phonon module like AudioOutput and VolumeSlider but had no luck.
There is one example on the Qt website but that itself uses Media Player, for which we can control the volume.

Please advise on how can we get rid of this problem.
It looks like this is a limitation of QWebView based application as of now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Flash manages it's own volume and you cannot access it from Qt.